# Is "Dollar-sign" optional in powershell "$()"?

Tags: powershell

I've seen an example for setting the timestamps (creationtime, lastaccesstime, lastwritetime) of a file with powershell:

```
PS>$(get-item test.txt).lastwritetime=$(get-date "01/01/2020")
```

which seems to work.

This page: http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html about powershell operators says that `"$( )"` is a "SubExpression operator".

But it also seems to work without the `"$"` like:

```
PS>(get-item test.txt).lastwritetime=(get-date "01/01/2020")
```

and most powershell examples I've seen omit the `"$"` when using parenthesis.

So, is the "Dollar-sign" optional in powershell `"$()"` ? Or is there some difference with/without the `"$"` that I'm just not seeing.

Is `"$()"` and `"()"` actually 2 different operators that just happen to both be valid uses in the examples I have shown?

Answer (score 3):

You need the $ sign to denote a sub expression if you use multiple statements or the statement is embedded in a string. Parenthesis without the $ is just a grouping operator.

```
$($x = 1; $y =2; $x + $y).tostring() //3

($x = 1; $y =2; $x + $y).tostring() // invalid syntax

($x = 1 + 2).tostring() //3

"$(1 +2)"  //3
```

Answer (score 0):

The first time I need of `$()` was inside a string :

```
$a = Get-Process "explorer"
Write-host "$a.Name" -> System.Diagnostics.Process (explorer).Name
Write-Host "$($a.Name)" -> explorer
```

I also use it each time I want PowerShell to force compute something first.