# What does the “$” symbol do in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I've seen the $ symbol used in PowerShell with every variable. Is there any specific use of this symbol?

Comment: Dollar signs are used for variables, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_variables?view=powershell-6. It is also used to denote a subexpression, like: `$()`, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39461670/1701026

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dollar symbol in PowerShell variable is used to set/evaluate the value of that variable.

```
$Variable1 = hello
```

Above expression is to define a vriable by setting it a value `hello`. Here the variable name is `Variable1`, but with `$` it is setting the `Variable1` a value `hello`.

There are cmdlets to set variables where `$` is not used.

```
Set-Variable -Name Variable2 -Value HelloWorld
```

And get cmdlet for the same.

```
Get-Variable -Name Variable2
```

PS: Above explanation is only for variables.

Answer (score 0):

Use for define variable.

```
$Variable1 = "hello"
```