# Invoke-SqlCmd generates an exception when used in a loop that contains another Invoke-SqlCmd

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm having an issue with calling `Invoke-SqlCmd` when it contains a second `Invoke-SqlCmd` call:

```
function Get-Foo
{

  $query=`
@"
WITH data AS 
(
  SELECT  1 ID, 'A' NAME
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  2 ID, 'B' NAME
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  3 ID, 'C' NAME
)
SELECT  *
FROM    data
"@

  Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance "SERVER" -Database "DATABASE" -Query $query

}

function Get-Bar
{
  param
  (
    [int]$ParentId
  )

  $query=`
@"
WITH data AS 
(
  SELECT  1 ID, 'A' NAME, 1 PARENT_ID
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  2 ID, 'B' NAME, 1 PARENT_ID
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  3 ID, 'C' NAME, 2 PARENT_ID
)
SELECT  *
FROM    data
WHERE   parent_id = $ParentId
"@

  Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance "SERVER" -Database "DATABASE" -Query $query

}

Get-Foo | ForEach-Object {

  Get-Bar -ParentId $_.ID

}
```

The first iteration of the outer loop works fine, but when it attempts the the second iteration, and exception is generated:

> Invoke-SqlCmd : The WriteObject and WriteError methods cannot be
>   called from outside the overrides of the  BeginProcessing,
>   ProcessRecord, and EndProcessing methods, and they can only be called
>   from within the same  thread. Validate that the cmdlet makes these
>   calls correctly, or contact Microsoft Customer Support Services. At
>   Untitled-1.ps1:18  char:3
>   +   Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance "SERVER" -Database "DATABASE ...
>   +   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (SERVER:PSObject) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], PSInvalidOperationExceptio     n
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExecutionFailed,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand

This syntax works, however:

```
$foo = Get-Foo
$foo | ForEach-Object {

  Get-Bar

}
```

I'm guessing that I need to close the first `Invoke-SqlCmd`, but perhaps there is another solution.

Answer (score 3):

This is related to the way the PowerShell pipeline works (see [Understanding pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/understanding-the-powershell-pipeline?view=powershell-6)), and a limitation in `Invoke-SqlCmd` where it doesn't like running more than one query in parallel.

To illustrate, let's rewrite your example as follows:

```bsh
function Invoke-SqlCmd
{
    write-output "aaa";
    write-output "bbb";
    write-output "ccc";
}

function Get-Foo
{
    write-host "Get-Foo started";
    Invoke-SqlCmd;
    write-host "Get-Foo finished";
}

function Get-Bar
{
    param( $value )
    write-host "Get-Bar '$value'";
}
```

and now run this script:

```bsh
write-host "using pipelines"
Get-Foo | foreach-object { Get-Bar $_ }
```

which gives this output:

```
using pipelines
Get-Foo started
Get-Bar 'aaa'
Get-Bar 'bbb'
Get-Bar 'ccc'
Get-Foo finished
```

If you look at the output, you can see that the "Get-Bar" commands are being called while Get-Foo is still "active" in the pipeline.

Compare to this:

```bsh
write-host "using immediate evaluation"
(Get-Foo) | foreach { Get-Bar $_ }
```

which gives:

```
using immediate evaluation
Get-Foo started
Get-Foo finished
Get-Bar 'aaa'
Get-Bar 'bbb'
Get-Bar 'ccc'
```

where Get-Foo is executed to completion before the values are piped into Get-Bar.

Your specific error is due to your script using multiple concurrent pipeline steps but `Invoke-SqlCmd` not supporting multiple concurrent pipeline steps. Fortunately you can tell PowerShell to use "immediate evaluation" instead in a few different ways, including the approaches mentioned in other answers:

- assigning the expression to a temporary variable first:

```bsh
$foo = Get-Foo;
$foo | ForEach-Object { Get-Bar $_ }
```

- using the [SubExpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6#subexpression-operator--) in your script (note the $ is optional in some cases as per [Is "Dollar-sign" optional in powershell "$()"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39461585/is-dollar-sign-optional-in-powershell))

```bsh
(Get-Foo) | Foreach-Object { Get-Bar $_ }
```

- or wrap Invoke-SqlCmd in a subexpression inside your function. (This one is a bit misleading because Get-Foo is still active in the pipeline *but* Invoke-SqlCmd is evaluated immediately).

```bsh
function Get-Foo
{
    write-host "Get-Foo started";
    (Invoke-SqlCmd);
    write-host "Get-Foo finished";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I cannot explain *why* this isn't working (although it looks like the threads are being mixed and the .NET provider cannot handle it properly).

What does work (but this is basically the same as your proposal of assigning it to a variable first) is to surround Get-Foo by parentheses:

```
(Get-Foo) | Foreach-Object { Get-Bar }
```

You can also experiment with the `-Begin`, `-Process` and `-End` parameters of Foreach-Object:

```
Get-Foo | ForEach-Object -Process {$_} -End { Get-Bar }
```

Comment: while my example didn't show it, I need the `$_.ID` from the first query as a parameter for the second.  As such, I need to call `Get-Bar` in the `Process` block.  I adjusted the question to reflect this.

Comment: Wrapping the `Invoke-SqlCmd` call in parentheses must force the `DataRow`'s connection to close.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Defending Invoke-SqlCmd](http://www.mikefal.net/2017/03/15/defending-invoke-sqlcmd/), I decided to implement my own `Invoke-SqlCmd` cmdlet:

```
function Invoke-SqlCmd
{

  [cmdletbinding()]
  param
  (
    [string]$ServerInstance,
    [string]$Database,
    [string]$Query
  )

  Write-Debug $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name
  Write-Debug "$ServerInstance.$Database"

  try {
    $Connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection

    $Connection.ConnectionString = "server=$ServerInstance;database=$Database;trusted_connection=true;"
    $Connection.Open()

    $Command = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
    $Command.Connection = $Connection
    $Command.CommandText = $Query

    $DataAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $Command
    $Dataset = New-Object System.Data.Dataset

    $DataAdapter.Fill($Dataset) | Out-Null # suppress record count

    $Dataset.Tables[0]
  }
  catch 
  {
    Write-Error $_
  }
  finally
  {
    $Connection.Close()
  }

}
```

This implementation will be used instead of the 'regular' `Invoke-SqlCmd` cmdlet in my functions.

The loop works as expected.